# Android Array to Marquee list

Tags: android, arrays, listview, textview, jquery-ui-selectable

What would the best approach for getting a array into a selectable (marquee) list.

I have a list of items that don't display as text is too long, so they need marqueed, these also need to be selectable.

Would a listview or a textview be the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In the XML Set

```
<TextView
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
/>
```

Inside OnCreate() of Activity

```
    textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    textView.setText("Get_Strings_From_Array");
    textView.setSelected(true);
    textView.setSingleLine(true);
    textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for this - but will this allow me to select each item.

Comment: yes. 'textView.setTextIsSelectable(true)' - will allow you to select the items individually.